# HIbernate: Could not determine type for class

Tags: java, hibernate

That's my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "instagram_token")
    private Token instagramToken;

    @Column(name = "paypal_credential")
    private SignatureCredential signatureCredential;
```

Token and SignatureCredential are 3rd party classes. Hibernates determine type for Token, but can't do the same for SignatureCredential and I don't understand why.

```
public class Token implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 715000866082812683L;
    private final String rawResponse;
    private final String secret;
    private final String token;


public class SignatureCredential implements ICredential {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String applicationId;
    private String signature;
    private ThirdPartyAuthorization thirdPartyAuthorization;

public interface ThirdPartyAuthorization {

}
```

Comment: could you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: _"Hibernates determine type for Token"_ How did you confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Token entity implements `Serializable`, which is a valid type for an Entity property. On the other hand, SignatureCredential is not implementing `Serializable`, nor is any type that is recognized by Hibernate to be as valid Entity type. Unless, `ICredential` interface extends `Serializable` interface (which I don't see in your code).

See: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types

In JPA here are valid simple types that can be mapped:

- Primitive Java types: byte, int, short, long, boolean, char, float, double
- Wrapper classes of primitive Java types: Byte, Integer, Short, Long, Boolean, Character, Float, Double
- Byte and character array types: byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[]
- Large numeric types: java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigDecimalStrings:
- java.lang.String
- Java temporal types: java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar
- JDBC temporal types: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp
- Enumerated types: Any system or user-defined enumerated type
- Serializable objects: Any system or user-defined serializable type